# How can we check context object list for observer in magento2

Tags: magento2, event-observer, methods, object

I want to know context object list which we can use methods directly from $context object in Observer.

Just like in below URl.

**Magento2 – Use Defined Methods from Context Object**
URL:- https://webkul.com/blog/magento2-use-defined-methods-context/

Please help me if anybody have answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple php function `get_class_methods` to list all methods of object.

```
get_class_methods($object)
```

Comment: I am unable to get use defined methods from context object in observer in by above function in magento2.

Comment: Can we use context in observer in magento2 ? please let me know.

Comment: No, Becuase observer does not inherit, does not extended so it hasn't parent context. You can use the observer's dispatched function class as a subject in `execute()`

Answer (score 0):

You can't, because there is no context in Magento 2 observers and plugins